# qemu-guest-agent.service not starting in OpenStack

Tags: openstack, qemu, openstack-nova

I have installed OpenStack in Centos machine through the packstack.after deployment, the instnace is unable to change the password. Please help on this

```
****[root@myhost1 ~(keystone_admin)]# openstack server set --root-password instance-1


New password: 
Retype new password: 
QEMU guest agent is not enabled (HTTP 409) (Request-ID: req-00802f04-4c57-40ec-9c75-a429e13859e5)****

[root@myhost1 ~(keystone_admin)]# systemctl start qemu-guest-agent.service


A dependency job for qemu-guest-agent.service failed. See 'journalctl -xe' for details.

root@myhost1 ~(keystone_admin)]# systemctl status  qemu-guest-agent.service


● qemu-guest-agent.service - QEMU Guest Agent
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/qemu-guest-agent.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)

Sep 27 12:58:13 myhost1.example.com systemd[1]: Dependency failed for QEMU Guest Agent.
Sep 27 12:58:13 myhost1.example.com systemd[1]: Job qemu-guest-agent.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Sep 27 13:13:07 myhost1.example.com systemd[1]: Dependency failed for QEMU Guest Agent.
Sep 27 13:13:07 myhost1.example.com systemd[1]: Job qemu-guest-agent.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Sep 27 13:20:29 myhost1.example.com systemd[1]: Dependency failed for QEMU Guest Agent.
Sep 27 13:20:29 myhost1.example.com systemd[1]: Job qemu-guest-agent.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Sep 27 14:32:50 myhost1.example.com systemd[1]: Dependency failed for QEMU Guest Agent.
Sep 27 14:32:50 myhost1.example.com systemd[1]: Job qemu-guest-agent.service/start failed with result 'dependency'
[root@myhost1 ~(keystone_admin)]#
```

Comment: Any success with your problem? Thanks for an update.

Answer (score 0):

Request you to provide more detail. Please provide output of "journalctl -xe" ones you start "qemu-guest-agent.service".